# How can I append a dynamic text with a static text in html?

Tags: asp.net, html, authentication, append

I'm working on a login page, I want the user to see his name beside Welcome"X" when he login.. 
Is there a method to do so in html with asp.net or jquery ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes there is. You do some programming with the database and ... voilá

Comment: This is a very low quality question.  Can you flesh it out some more?  Maybe show some code that you are trying to get working?

Comment: Ok I'll. Thanks for your valuable feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Login aspx page , after successful login set a session variable :

```
session["userName"] = "userName";
```

And show the same into label in the next page load event  with welcome text :

```
if( session["userName"]!=null)
    lblUserName.Text= "Welcome " + session["userName"].toString()
```

Or You could access it like below in you aspx page :

```
Welcome <%=Server.HtmlEncode(Session["userName"])%>
```

with .Net 4 you may want to use [code block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178135.aspx) :

```
Welcome <%:Session["userName"]%>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Excuse me where should I write this line: Welcome <%=Server.HtmlEncode(Session["userName"])%>

Answer (score 1):

Here's something like one way the flow could work:

1. User logs in, credentials are sent to server (ASP) via POST
2. ASP checks credentials with database to make sure that user/pass combination are in fact "good"
3. ASP starts a "session" for that user
4. ASP now redirects them to the welcome/logged in/home page
5. The welcome/logged in/home page is a new ASP (script?) that does the following:

   1. Uses the username stored in the session to look up the user's name in the database (something like `SELECT name FROM Users WHERE username = \' . session["username"] . '\''`
   2. Outputs the dynamic html with the user's name that we just got from the DB

I'm not too familiar with ASP and sorry for not posting any code, but this is what I'd do in PHP. From your question it sounds like you aren't too familiar with the difference between client side and server side and I think these steps will point you in the right direction in being able to google what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [`LoginStatus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginstatus.aspx)  to show the username. You get the `UserName` of the currently logged in user by `Membership.GetUser().ToString()`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178332.aspx

```
LoginStatus1.LogoutText = "Logout: " +  Membership.GetUser().ToString();
```